# sql calc found rows in mysqli not returning the exact number of records

Tags: php, mysqli

The sql calc found rows in mysqli is not returning the exact number of records (numrange). I get : 1. It should work fine.

```
$sQuery1 = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
            sv_cam.image,
            sv_cam.cam_id,
            sv_cam.alt,
            sv_orte.resort,
            sv_orte.resort_us,        
            sv_country.sym,
            DATE_FORMAT(sv_cam.lud, '%b %d') as stat
      FROM  sv_cam
      LEFT JOIN sv_orte ON sv_cam.res_id = sv_orte.res_id AND status=0
      INNER JOIN sv_canton ON sv_orte.can_id = sv_canton.can_id
      INNER JOIN sv_country ON sv_canton.cou_id = sv_country.cou_id
      WHERE (lud >= DATE_SUB('$today', INTERVAL 30 DAY))  ORDER BY lud desc, sv_cam.cam_id desc LIMIT $offset, $cams";
//echo $sQuery1;
$sResult1=mysqli_query($conn, $sQuery1);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($sResult1);
//if ($numrows<1) { exit; }


$numrange=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
echo $numrange;
```

Comment: Why are you rounding?

Comment: removed it. it was part of an other procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function returns the [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. Therefore you need to fetch your results.

```php
$sResult2 = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total');
$found_rows = mysqli_fetch_object($sResult2);

echo 'total rows'.$found_rows->total;
```